# Error when install pylibmc using pip

Tags: python, memcached, osx-lion, libmemcached

Hello when I attempt to install pylibmc on OSX Lion using pip I get the following error:

```
./_pylibmcmodule.h:42:10: fatal error: 'libmemcached/memcached.h' file not found

#include <libmemcached/memcached.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any clues at how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the libmemcached headers installed anywhere?

Comment: Thanks, I faced this error while installing requirements for running djangoproject's tests. Posting it here so that if somehow new contributors face this issue and reach here, they can confidently rely on the solution `brew install libmemcached`

Answer (score 143, accepted):

libmemcached may also be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
brew install libmemcached
```

After that, `pip install pylibmc` worked for me without needing to specify any additional arguments.

Comment: I installed it using homebrew and it was correctly linked, although pylibmc couldn't find it either way. So I had to point the libmemcached directory when installing pylibmc by running `sudo pip install pylibmc --install-option="--with-libmemcached=/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18/"`

Comment: You can try `brew unlink libmemcached`, then `brew link libmemcached`. In my case the links were messed up. This should create links such that `/usr/local/include/libmemcached/memcached.h` exists.

Comment: These solutions didn't work for me.  I had to ```export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"``` and ```export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"```

Comment: `brew unlink libmemcached` then `brew link memcached` worked for me! Thanks @Neil

Comment: The defaults have changed at some point and you need to make sure CFLAGS/LDFLAGS are set. The best way to do this is to use `pkg-config` (`brew install pkg-config` if you don't have it) so the current installed version is used for the include & library files:

`CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags libmemcached) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs libmemcached) pip install pylibmc`

Comment: I am installing pylibmc on windows but it is failing due to libmemcached and while installing libmemcached it is giving error of cmemcached_imp.c cannot be executed? Any help for windows platform @ChrisAdams

Comment: With modern installations of Homebrew, you may need to point to the new Homebrew root which is no longer in /usr/local: `LIBMEMCACHED=/opt/homebrew pip install pylibmc`

Comment: `CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include" pipenv install` worked for me for M1, have not tried the shorter path though.

Answer (score 38):

It's in the libmemcached package. To install it using macports:

`sudo port install libmemcached`

Then, assuming you're using pip:

`pip install pylibmc --install-option="--with-libmemcached=/opt/local"`

or

`LIBMEMCACHED=/opt/local pip install pylibmc`

as explained in the [pylibmc docs](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/install.html#from-pypi).

Comment: Worked, but I had to prepend a 'sudo' before the pip

Answer (score 33):

I solved this issue by checking where memcached is installed

```
$ which memcached
/usr/local/bin/memcached
```

and then setting LIBMEMCACHED environment variable before pip install:

```
$ export LIBMEMCACHED=/usr/local
$ pip install pylibmc
```

Comment: By the way, I have OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This is the on for El Capitan

Comment: Works for me on macOS Sierra^^

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Mojave, python3.7

Comment: memcached not found

Answer (score 18):

Answer for Ubuntu users:

```
sudo apt install libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Fixed it for me! Verified on `18.0.4 lts`

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem because i have installed MEMCACHED and not LIBMEMCACHED, so, to resolve:

```
brew uninstall memcached #to remove wrong package

brew install libmemcached #install correct lib

pip install pylibmc
```

Its Works for me!

: )

Comment: Brew declined to uninstall memcached because libmemcached is an installed dependency; so I expect what you've actually done is reinstall `memcached`.

Answer (score 6):

For those finding this answer on Fedora:

`sudo yum install libmemcached-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Hit the same error with macOS High Sierra, Python3.6 installed with brew. Solution for me was to export these flags, mentioned in this comment: [Error when install pylibmc using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803310/error-when-install-pylibmc-using-pip/33663121#comment62898499_19432949)

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
```

After that, `pip install` run just fine.

Answer (score 2):

i fixed this by installing memcached from port

you should install first macports from http://www.macports.org/

then run this command

```
sudo port install memcached
```

after that download the pylibmc from the pypi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibmc
extract .tar.gz file then

```
python setup.py install --with-libmemcached=/opt/local
```

Answer (score 2):

this code is worked for me

```
  sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev

  LIBMEMCACHED=/opt/local pip install pylibmc
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with osx 14.1.1 on an M1 Mac:

```
brew install libmemcached
export LIBMEMCACHED="/opt/homebrew"

pip install pylibmc
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the X-Code Command Line Tools need to be installed.

```
 xcode-select -p
```